# Implementing a sticky footer in Orchard CMS

Tags: customization, orchardcms

Can somebody please explain how a sticky footer:

```
 <div id="container....
  ...content
 </div>
 <div id="footer"....
 </div>

 CSS:
 #container
 {
   height: 100%;
   margin-bottom: -height of footer
 }
```

might be implemented in Orchard CMS?
 The problem I can't manage is to envelop some main content layouts in a wrapper.
 Currently I have:

```
 <div id="aside-1 ...
 <div id="layout-navigation
 <div id="layout-main-container
 <div id="layout-footer
```

So main problem is to customize layouts rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Layout.cshtml file, use the Display method to render zones. The primary zone where content gets rendered is the Content zone, which you render like this:

```
<div id="container....
  @Display(Model.Content)
 </div>
 <div id="footer"....
 </div>
```

You can also define your own custom zones (via your Theme.txt manifest file).
For example, in your Theme.txt file, define a Footer zone like this:

```
Zones: Content, Footer
```

Then in Layout.cshtml, render that zone like this:

```
<div id="container....
  @Display(Model.Content)
 </div>
 <div id="footer"....
  @Display(Model.Footer)
 </div>
```

You have complete freedom on how you want to layout content.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please also give some advice regarding where main community usually is? Is it of SO, or on forums by `discussions` link from main project website?

Comment: Codeplex discussions https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions . Helpful people on SO too